# Units for distance in the Inverse Square Law

Tags: radiation, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I've looked around quite a bit and can find no definitive explanation of which units to use when utilizing the inverse square (or cube) law.  I can find the top level explanation: if you double the distance between a radiative source and the target, the energy is cut by 4, all over the place.  But this is a top level explanation.  It does not actually indicate how to use this information.  For instance, if I'm calculating radiative drop of energy from the earth to the sun, do I use meters?  Kilometers?  Miles?

I've come up with two possible interpretations to this:

1. Use the unit for the energy type.  For instance, Joules are Newton/Meters.  Ergo, you would use meters.
2. Use the diametric cross section of the object perpendicular to the path of radiation.  In other words, in the previous example you would divide the distance between the Sun and Earth by the diameter of the Earth.  As long as you measure both in the same units, they will cancel out, leaving a pure number.

The more I think about it, the more I think the latter is the correct answer.  But I'd greatly appreciate some confirmation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you are calculating the *ratio* of the values of a quantity at two different distances - in which case the unit of distance does not matter since all you need is the ratio of the distances - or whether you are calculating the *absolute value* of a quantity at a given distance, in which case the units of distance must be consistent with the units of the constant of proportionality that you are using.

For example, if you are calculating the acceleration due to gravity at a distance above the Earth's surface equal to the radius of the Earth then you have doubled the distance from the centre of the Earth, so you know that the acceleration due to gravity at this distance is a quarter what it is on the surface of the Earth. But if you want to calculate the absolute value of the gravitational acceleration at this distance and the value you are using for the gravitational constant $G$ is in units of $\text{m}^3\text{kg}^{-1}\text{s}^{-2}$ then you must measure your distance from the centre of the Earth in metres and the mass of the Earth in kilogrammes, and the result will be in $\text{ms}^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way similar to your method 2), using areas.  The surface area of a sphere is $4\pi{r}^2$, so if you do a $\pi r^2$ for the earth and divide by $4\pi{r_s}^2$ where $r_s$ is the earth-sun distance, you'd find the fraction of the sun's radiation that landed on the earth.

As you said, any length units work as they'd cancel out.

If you are calculating the energy arriving on one square meter at a certain distance from the sun, then it's best to use the standard science (SI) units of meters.

For example you could divide the total energy output of the sun per second, by the $4\pi{r}^2$, to find the energy arriving at each square meter, per second, a distance $r$ from the sun.